# How can I use the path with "ApplicationData" in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So what I want to do is something like this:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="BookData" Source="(LocalApplicationData)\MyApp\bookdata.xml" XPath="Books"/>
```

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

However, I don't know how I can use the *LocalApplicationData* path in XAML.

In the C# code, it would be something like

```
source = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), @"MyApp\bookdata.xml");
```

How can I do this in XAML?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot do this in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two ways off the top of my head:

1) Use a converter to simply return the value of `LocalApplicationData`

2) Create a custom markup extension to bind to: http://10rem.net/blog/2011/03/09/creating-a-custom-markup-extension-in-wpf-and-soon-silverlight

I would doubt that you can do this directly in XAML without any 'extra' code required, but if you dont want to pollute your ViewModels and other application specific code, I would go with one of these options.